# Npgsql Error 42601 syntax error at or near "["

Tags: npgsql

I am getting this exception on the InitializeDataBaseConnection(). The exception is
Npgsql.NpgsqlException was unhandled by user code. It appears that the SQL generated has square brackets for table and column names and Npgsql is not liking it. How can I get around this error?

Here is my SimpleMembershipProvider constructor:

```
public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
{
Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

try
{
    using (var context = new UsersContext())
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }

    WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDBContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: false);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw new InvalidOperationException("The ASP.NET Simple Membership database could not be initialized. For more information, please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=256588", ex);
}
}


  **Message=ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "["**
  Source=Npgsql
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  BaseMessage=syntax error at or near "["

  Code=42601
  Detail=""
  **ErrorSql=SELECT [UserId] FROM [UserProfile] WHERE (UPPER([UserName]) = ((E'Z')))**
  File=src\backend\parser\scan.l
  Hint=""
  Line=1044
  Position=8
  Routine=scanner_yyerror
  Severity=ERROR
  Where=""
  StackTrace:
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlState.cs:line 850
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextResponseObject() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1173
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.GetNextRowDescription() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1191
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader.NextResult() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1377
       at Npgsql.ForwardsOnlyDataReader..ctor(IEnumerable`1 dataEnumeration, CommandBehavior behavior, NpgsqlCommand command, NotificationThreadBlock threadBlock, Boolean synchOnReadError) in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlDataReader.cs:line 1040
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.GetReader(CommandBehavior cb) in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 611
       at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() in C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlCommand.cs:line 722
       at WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args)
       at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
       at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(IDatabase db, String userTableName, String userNameColumn, String userIdColumn, String userName)
       at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUserTable()
  InnerException:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote '"' instead of '[' and ']'. In PostGreSql if alias names contain spaces you can double quote them. If alias names do not have spaces in between double quoting is not necessary.